# How to use seahorse to store and fetch bitwarden or lastpass master password?

Tags: security, password, seahorse

I am using the bitwarden password manager add on for firefox.
If I set "remember password" for the master password, bitwarden warns me that the password will be stored in plain text on my pc which is insecure.

My question is; **is it possible to store my bitwarden master password in seahorse (linux Passwords and Keys), so I will be able to automatically login to bitwarden every time I open my browser in a secure way.**

Thanks.